# Having hard time compiling async/await to polyfills [babel + webpack]

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Having hard time tinkering with babel + webpack to make it compile to support older browsers. Babel plugins are not working, I bet there's problem in webpack config. Or may be some weird edge case bug crawled in the rc version of babel (7.0.0-rc1).

**Steps to reproduce:**

follow instructions in readme:
https://github.com/hyphen-wrex/babel-bug

**Expected result:**

code (async/await) is compiled down to es5 + polyfills are present

**Actual result:**

code is not compiled, older browsers (chrome 48, for instance) aren't able to pick up the code

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the help of babel community. Problem is in config. The thread is here: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8495